# Visualforce textarea and line breaks

Tags: visualforce

I am having some trouble with line breaks in Visualforce versus the standard UI.

It seems that in Visualforce textarea fields (generated with apex:inputfield) save line breaks as \n (char 10) but the regular UI saves them as \r\n (char 13 char 10). 
This is creating a problem down the line because I have a trigger that is looking for changes to fields and it flagging those fields as changed when saved later from the default UI because it is converting the line breaks.

I could create a workaround by using a regex to replace all single \n with \r\n on save for all the fields this applies to, but I was wondering if anyone had a better solution that I am missing. I haven't tried on other platforms or browsers to know if that is causing the problem, but regardless I am using the same setup as 95% of the company is using.

Visualforce Save  with Char Array
[image: Visualforce Save]

UI Save with Char Array
[image: UI Save]